# Prolog if clause returns false

Tags: prolog

I am learning Prolog and I have a small question.
I'm working on an example which "builds" a tower.

So I define 3 blocks a, b and c.
The third block c lays on top of a and b -> so it is supported by a and b.

```
block(a).
block(b).
block(c).

%supported(BLOCK, BY1, BY2)
supported(c,a,b).


level(BLOCK, LEVEL) :-
      supported(BLOCK, X, _)
   -> (level(X, LEV1), LEVEL is LEV1 + 1)
   ;  LEVEL is 0.
```

I also have a function to calculate the level of a block. The problem I have is the following:

```
?- level(X, 0).
false.

?- level(X, 1).
X = c.
```

Why is it returning false for the level 0 and how can i fix it?
I would like to have a method which returns me a and b for level 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider that

```
?- level(a,0).
true.
```

it's evident that when `BLOCK` is free the `supported(BLOCK, X, _)` succeeds, forcing the rule on the unintended conjuntion `level(X, LEV1), LEVEL is LEV1 + 1`, that indeed fails.

To correct the behaviour, bind `BLOCK`:

```
level(BLOCK, LEVEL) :-
  block(BLOCK),
  (supported(BLOCK, X, _) -> level(X, LEV1), LEVEL is LEV1 + 1 ; LEVEL is 0).
```

Answer (score 1):

One can debug this using `trace.` (added indentation):

```
[trace]  ?- level(X, 0).
   Call: (6) level(_G2697, 0) ? creep
     Call: (7) supported(_G2697, _G2771, _G2772) ? creep
     Exit: (7) supported(c, a, b) ? creep
     Call: (7) level(a, _G2771) ? creep
       Call: (8) supported(a, _G2771, _G2772) ? creep
       Fail: (8) supported(a, _G2771, _G2772) ? creep
     Redo: (7) level(a, _G2771) ? creep
       Call: (8) _G2770 is 0 ? creep
       Exit: (8) 0 is 0 ? creep
     Exit: (7) level(a, 0) ? creep
     Call: (7) 0 is 0+1 ? creep
     Fail: (7) 0 is 0+1 ? creep
   Fail: (6) level(_G2697, 0) ? creep
   false.
```

So what happened?

First you call `level(X,0).` This predicate calls supported with `supported(BLOCK,X,_).` There is one answer that unifies: `BLOCK=a`, `X=b` and `_=c`. So that means the *if-then-else* statement uses the *then*-part.

In the then-part, it queries `level/2` again with `level(b,LEV1)`, now this call results in a call to `support(b,LEV1,_)`. For this call, it can't resolve the call, because there is no `support` predicate with the first value `b`. So now we take the else-part. We unify `LEV1 is 0`, thus `LEV1=0` and we return.

In the return part (in the then-part), `level(b,0)` is the result. Now we unify `LEVEL is LEV1+1`, `LEVEL` however was already grounded as `0` and `0+1` is `1`. Thus it fails on the top level.

The resolution is probably to make `supported` finer, and define it as: `support/2`.

The program reads:

```
block(a).
block(b).
block(c).

%supported(BLOCK, BY1, BY2)
supported(c,b).
supported(c,a).
supported(b,a).
```

Now the `level` predicate reads:

```
level(B,L) :-
    supported(B,C),
    level(C,LC),
    L is LC+1.
level(_,0).
```